# Minimize $\mathrm{tr}(XYX^{-1}Y')$ subject to inequality constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Given $a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $a_1\geq a_2>0$. Solve the following:

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathrm{tr}(XYX^{-1}Y')\\\quad X,Y\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}\\ \text{subject to} & YY'=\mathrm{diag\{a_1,a_2\}}\\&X>0\end{array}

If we assume $X$ and $Y$ are diagonal matrices, then best we can achieve is $\mathrm{tr}(XYX^{-1}Y')=a_1+a_2$.

I tried to use SVD on $Y$ and other tricks to simplify, but didn't get much.

Edit: $Y'$ is the transpose of $Y$, $X>0$ means $X$ is positive definite.

Comment: Please clarify what is $Y'$ in your question. Also, are $Y$ and $Y'$ fixed?

Comment: @user1551 i have edited the question. We only know $YY'$, but we dont know $Y$.

Comment: The constraint $YY'=\mbox{diag}(a_{1},a_{2})$ makes the feasible set non-convex.  You won't be able to formulate this as an SDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum possible value is $2\sqrt{a_1a_2}$, because
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}(XYX^{-1}Y^T)
&=\|X^{1/2}YX^{-1/2}\|_F^2\\
&\ge\sum_{i=1}^2|\lambda_i(X^{1/2}YX^{-1/2})|^2\quad\text{(by Schur triangulation)}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^2|\lambda_i(Y)|^2\\
&\ge2\prod_{i=1}^2|\lambda_i(Y)|\\
&=2|\det(Y)|\\
&=2\sqrt{a_1a_2}
\end{align}
and equalities hold when $X=\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{a_2},\sqrt{a_1})$ and $Y=\pmatrix{0&\sqrt{a_1}\\ \sqrt{a_2}&0}$.